# Bootstrap Responsive Images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm new to Web Development and bootstrap and I'm curious as to how the author of this page http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0196957 was able to get the background image the way that they have it. It's faded in the back so that the text on-top of it is readable yet extremely eye-catching.

Comment: In desktop view it looks nice but through Android chrome Browser the top and bottom of the site causes the image to `jump`

Comment: It will be helpful for you to use the developer tools in your browser (usually F12 or right click -> inspect element) and understand how the page is constructed/organized. In your example, it is an `img` tag which contains the image, and its parent `div` has a black dotted image with 0.35 opacity set over it which gives the effect. (it doesn't have much to do with Bootstrap, but a LOT to do with CSS)

Comment: Wow that was an extremely quick response, I definitely appreciate the help! Also for some reason I'm unable to upvote your answer.

Comment: Actually you can find a bunch of tutorials on how to customize bootstrap css. I recommend this [tutorial](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/) here. It will help you customize and make bootstrap behave the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you're referring to the option text/read more from the site you posted. The effect you are seeing is the standard behaviour of a modal dialog, which when shown grays out the surrounding area making it unclickable - the idea being that you focus on the dialog and attend to it first before you do anything else. [See here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for how to use a dialog in bootstrap.